# How to know which version of apps been used in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-apps

I have been using django for my web project. I forgot to add requirements.txt file. Now I have already installed so many apps even third party apps. How do I know which version of apps I have been installed and their names?

### Comand line

This is the comand line I used to know which apps been using in the django project but the thing is I can only get the few app names with this comand not the version.

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

Comment: You can use `pip freeze` to obtain the list of installed packages.

Comment: you can use `pip freeze > requirement.txt` will create requiremen.txt file containing all packages with version.Hope it will help you.

Comment: @Moon  Thank you for this valuable information

Comment: Welcome on SO, I have the impression you have profoundly edited your question in to a new one. Why have you edited entirely into a new question ? I think you'd rather ask a new question instead. You'd get more related answers.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to be something completely different from what you asked before, especially if you already have an answer and it was marked as a duplicate. This creates confusion and is not how this site functions. Instead, create a new question and ask about your other problems there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For creating `requirements.txt` file, run the following command inside the virtual environment:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

It will create a `requirements.txt` file and prints the list of all the installed packages with their versions into the `requirements.txt` file.